# Oracle, Mysql, how to get average

Tags: sql, oracle, average

How to get Average fuel consumption only using MySQL or Oracle:

```
SELECT te.fuelName,
       zkd.fuelCapacity,
       zkd.odometer
  FROM ZakupKartyDrogowej zkd  
  JOIN TypElementu  te
    ON te.typElementu_Id = zkd.typElementu_Id  
   AND te.idFirmy = zkd.idFirmy
   AND te.typElementu_Id IN (3,4,5) 
 WHERE zkd.idFirmy = 1054 
   AND zkd.kartaDrogowa_Id = 42 
   AND zkd.data BETWEEN to_date('2015-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
                    AND to_date('2015-09-30','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

**Result of this query is:**

```
 fuelName | fuelCapacity | odometer |   tanking
-------------------------------------------------
   'ON'   |    534       |  1284172 | 2015-09-29
   'ON'   |    571       |  1276284 | 2015-09-02
   'ON'   |    470       |  1277715 | 2015-09-07
   'ON'   |    580.01    |  1279700 | 2015-09-11
   'ON'   |    490       |  1281103 | 2015-09-17
   'ON'   |    520       |  1282690 | 2015-09-23
```

We can do it later in `java` or `php`, but want to get result right away from query. How should we modify above query to do that?

`fuelCapacity` is the number of liters of fuel that has been poured into cartank at gas station.

Comment: what do the 2nd and 3rd columns mean (number, odometer ?)

Comment: Please translate the field names to english.

Comment: You have `fuelCapacity` and `odometer` and you want average consumption. How? You're giving no info on how to calculate it. If I have a car whose fuel capacity and odometer reading I know, I have no way of calculating average consumption.

Comment: As Antti29 said, your column names don't make sense and it's rather difficult to help you based on the given information. Once you have your dataset figured out, you can do calculated column, for example: `SELECT fuelused/dist AS consumption FROM yourtable`.

Comment: fuelCapacity is the amount you tanked on that day and you always make the tank full? So on 2015-09-29 you had driven a distance of 1284172-1276284=7888 and used 534 fuel on that distance? So you used an avarage of 0.07 fuel units per distance unit?

Comment: And you want to get the avarage consumption for each record or only one total avarage?

Comment: i want to get only one result so total average

Comment: Okay, one question answered. What about my other questions?

Comment: And I wonder what your actual problem is. Are you not able to find the *mathematical formula* and want us to tell you this? Or do you have the formula, but wanted to keep it a secret, and ask us for the *according query*? It can't possibly be *both*, can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one total average, what you need is the sum of the refills divided by the difference between the odometer readings at the start and the end, i.e. `fuel used / distance travelled`.

I don't have your table structure at hand, but this alteration to the `select` statement should do the trick:

```
select cast(sum(zkd.fuelCapacity) as float) / (max(zkd.odometer) - min(zkd.odometer)) as consumption ...
```

The `cast(field AS float)` does what the name implies, and typecasts the field as float, so the result will also be a float. (I do suspect that your `fuelCapacity` field is a float because there is one float value in your example, but this will make sure.)

Comment: That's about the answer I had in mind, when I asked my questions. I am just confused with the result 0.07 in my example; neither 0.07 l/km nor 0.07 l/m = 70 l/km seem to make much sense. I may be wrong, though. And it really only works when the tank gets filled completely. Anyway there is no need to cast to float in either of the DBMS. And you'd have to subtract the first fuelCapacity from sum(fuelCapacity), which is super-easy in Oracle and not as easy in MySQL.

Comment: @Antti29  your query is quicker from ours :) thanks and sorry for my poor english